# Given a Poisson distribution Poisson(n│λ) with expected value λ, which integer n is the most probable one?

Tags: conditional

- Given a Poisson distribution Poisson(n│λ) with expected value λ, which integer n is the most probable one?
- Prove that, if  is integer, there are two most probable values for .

Comment: This appears to be a tag:self-study question. Please read about the self-study tag and the associated policy. https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: See [The mode of a Poisson distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/246496/15941) over on math.SE.